# What are the Official Channels for learning SharePoint Development

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, development, learning

What are the Official Channels for learning SharePoint Development and what certification authorities exist?

This should extend to encompass SharePoint Online/ Cloud services/ Office 365 Development and On-Premise Solutions as well.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcse-productivity-certification.aspx and https://channel9.msdn.com/ and pluralsight.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could learn SharePoint development from the links below.

SharePoint development.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/

Development in SharePoint 2013.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj162979.aspx

Office 365 APIs platform overview.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/platform-development-overview